# Extract digits before using AVERAGEIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table with cells containing numbers from -1 to 10 (decimal places allowed). In some cases there is a trailing A behind the number.

Now, I would like to extract all digits from the cells and calculate the average *per row* using a formula but only consider elements that fulfill certain conditions:

a) The header does not contain "no" and

b) the value is >= 1, otherwise the value should not count towards the average.

The expected outcome is listed in the `average` column.

| average | yes | no | yes | yes | no | yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.75 | **2** | 2A | **3.5**A |  | -1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 4A | **3**A |  |  | **1** |

I tried this formula but excels tells me there is a problem and aborts.

`=AVERAGEIFS(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:G2, "A", "")), B1:G1, "<>*no*", B2:G2, ">=1", B2:G2, "<>")`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(d,B2:G2,
f,$B$1:$G$1,
d_,NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(d,"A","")),
AVERAGE(FILTER(d_,(f="yes")*(d_>=1))))
```

or as by row version:

```vb
=LET(data,B1:G3,
f,TAKE(data,1),
d_,NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(DROP(data,1),"A","")),
BYROW(d_,LAMBDA(r,AVERAGE(FILTER(r,(f="yes")*(r>=1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like if it is not working with `BYROW`