# How to write complex formula with openxlsx?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have the following table with cells containing numbers from -1 to 10 (decimal places allowed). In some cases there is a trailing A behind the number.

Now, I would like to extract all digits from the cells and calculate the average *per row* using a formula but only consider elements that fulfill certain conditions:

a) The header does not contain "no" and

b) the value is >= 1, otherwise the value should not count towards the average.

The expected outcome is listed in the `average` column.

| average | yes | no | yes | yes | no | yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.75 | **2** | 2A | **3.5**A |  | -1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 4A | **3**A |  |  | **1** |

I already got an very helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006678/extract-digits-before-using-averageifs) how to solve this using an advanced formula but now I am unable to implement this (or any other) solution using `openxlsx`

```
library(openxlsx)
values <- c(2, "2A", "3A", "", "-1", "0")
values2 <- c(0, "4A", "3A", "", "", "1")
df <- rbind(values,values2)
colnames(df) <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")

formula <- '=LET(data,B1:G3,
     f,TAKE(data,1),
     d_,NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(DROP(data,1),"A","")),
     BYROW(d_,LAMBDA(r,AVERAGE(FILTER(r,(f="yes")*(r>=1))))))'

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "test")
writeData(wb, "test", x = df)
writeFormula(wb, "test", x = formula, startCol = 8, startRow = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

When I try to open the file it say "We found a problem with some of the contents in test.xlsx". However, when I manually add the formula after the fact it works just fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See this [link](https://janmarvin.github.io/ox2-book/chapters/openxlsx2_formulas_manual.html#modern-spreadsheet-functions): modern excel formulas like lambda need a prefix. `_xlfn.`

Comment: @JanMarvin Thanks for your comment. So I'd need to switch to `openxlsx2` or is that also possible within `openxlsx`?

Comment: Should be possible in `openxlsx`, but maybe just give it a try :)

Comment: Here’s the `openxlsx2` answer: https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/discussions/950 This is an array formula that needs some extensive escaping. Should work with `openxlsx`, but I didn’t test this.

Comment: @JanMarvin Cool, thanks! It definitely works like a charm for `openxlsx2` and I appreciate you digging into this :) I did not get it to work with `openxlsx`, though.